# how to get integer value from textfield and retrieve the value to another class in java

Tags: java

How to get integer value from textfield and retrieve the value to another class in java ??

I know how to get but if i used in another class he get me 0 value,,,

> "this is in the GUI" x1,x2,y1,y2 predefined

```
private void X2_accesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){              
     x2=(int)(Double.parseDouble(X2_acces.getText())); 
}
```

I want to draw line the user inter 2 point (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) after that move the value to class draw line

> "this is in class drawLine"

```
Next_frame nf=new Next_frame();
Point2D.Double p2=new Point2D.Double(nf.x2,nf.y2);
```

Comment: How do you pass the parameter to another class?

Answer (score 0):

The following statement is quite ambigous.

```
x2=(int)(Double.parseDouble(X2_acces.getText()));
```

You are parsing the value as Double and casting it down to `int`. This is enough:

```
x2 = Integer.parseInt(x2_acces.getTest());
```

Now, when passing this value to another class, you have to make sure, that the method to which you are passing to accept the data type you are about to send.

**For example:**

For a class like this:

```
class DummyClass {
   public DummyClass(int X) {
      //Here note that 'x' is asking for a integer so you have to provide it with integer
   }
}
```

Then you have use them in the following order:

```
x2 = Integer.parseInt(x2_acces.getTest());
DummyClass c = new DummyClass(x2);
```